# How to layout collection cell in center?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I am trying to set collection cell in center of screen but not getting result as I want.

**1. Result as I want**

[image]

**2. Current output**

[image]

I have tried below code but not working.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize.init(width: 80, height: 80)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let totalCellWidth = 80 * 3
    let totalSpacingWidth = 10 * (3 - 1)

    let leftInset = (collectionView.frame.size.width - CGFloat(totalCellWidth + totalSpacingWidth)) / 2
    let rightInset = leftInset

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftInset, 0, rightInset)
}
```

> Updated following for better understanding.

**For 6 items it should look like this**

```
|x x x|
|x x x|
```

**For 5 items it should look like this**

```
|x x x|
| x x |
```

**For 4 items it should look like this**

```
|x x x|
|  x  |
```

Comment: just set appropriate content or section inset to `UICollectionView`

Comment: @SPatel Please review my updated questions. Thanks!

Comment: Why u r using this small number in UICollectionView? UIView ??

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let cellWidth : CGFloat = 80 * 3

    let numberOfCells = floor(self.view.frame.size.width / cellWidth)
    let edgeInsets = (self.view.frame.size.width - (numberOfCells * cellWidth)) / (numberOfCells + 1)

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, edgeInsets, 0, edgeInsets)
}
```

Comment: Yes dear, I tried that. but not working as per my need please check my updated question for more clarity.